# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[-1]

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Here is the problem

- Extract just the median_income column from the independent variables (from X_train and X_test).
- Perform Linear Regression to predict housing values based on median_income.
- Predict output for test dataset using the fitted model.
- Plot the fitted model for training data as well as for test data to check if the fitted model satisfies the test data.

I did a linear regression earlier. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/Users/saurabhsaha/Documents/PGP-AI:ML-Purdue/New/datasets')
df=pd.read_excel('California_housing.xlsx')
df.total_bedrooms=df.total_bedrooms.fillna(df.total_bedrooms.mean())
x = df.iloc[:,2:8]
y = df.median_house_value

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.20)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
california_model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)

california_model.predict(x_test)

Prdicted_values = pd.DataFrame(california_model.predict(x_test),columns=['Pred'])
```

Prdicted_values

```
Final = pd.concat([x_test.reset_index(drop=True),y_test.reset_index(drop=True),Prdicted_values],axis=1)
Final['Err_pct'] = abs(Final.median_house_value- 
Final.Pred)/Final.median_house_value
```

Here is my dataset- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vYngxWw7tqX8FpwkWB5G7Q9axhe9ipTu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114925088866643320785&rtpof=true&sd=true

Following is my code.

```py
x1_train=x_train.median_income
x1_train
x1_train.shape
x1_test=x_test.median_income
x1_test
type(x1_test)
x1_test.shape
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
california_model_new = LinearRegression().fit(x1_train,y_train)
```

I get an error right here and when I try converting my 2 D array to 1 D as follows , i can not

```py
import numpy as np
x1_train= x1_train.reshape(-1, 1)
x1_test = x1_train.reshape(-1, 1)
```

This is the error I get

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: does it work if you instead do x1_train.values.reshape(-1,1) ?

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values' getting this error

Comment: You need to keep track of the type of the various variables, and use the right methods.  If in doubt check the documentation.  A `pandas.Series` is a 1d object, and cannot be `reshaped`.  It has a `values, which is a 1d numpy array.  The array does not have a `values`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that x1_train is an instance of pd.Series and there is not .reshape() function for Series object. However .reshape() is used for numpy arrays.

Here is the code to understand this:

```
# A sample series
X = pd.Series([1,2,3,1,2])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64

# converting Series to numpy array
X = X.values

array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2])

# converting 1-D array to 2-D array
X.reshape(-1,1)

array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

For the problem on hand, the following code will help in resolving errors:

```
x1_train = x_train.median_income
type(x1_train)
pandas.core.series.Series

x1_train = x1_train.values #converting series to numpy array
x1_train
array([8.3252, 8.3014, 7.2574, ..., 1.7   , 1.8672, 2.3886])


# incase you need to convert it to 2-D array
x1_train = x1_train.reshape(-1,1)
x1_train
array([[8.3252],
       [8.3014],
       [7.2574],
       ...,
       [1.7   ],
       [1.8672],
       [2.3886]])
​
```

Answer (score 0):

`x1_train`  and `x1_test` are pandas Series objects, whereas the the `reshape()` method is applied to numpy arrays.

Do this instead:

```
x1_train= x1_train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
x1_test = x1_train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I am getting this AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: I just ran you code from the top with the provide file. When I run type(x1_train) after the train_test_split it tells that the its a pandas Series. Most likely there is some error in the way you executed you code. Try running it from the top. Or run the type(x1_train) command and see what is tells you.

Comment: Doesn't work. I put the problem too now in the description and the code I executed before this. I tried executing it from the top but I get the same error